# Count occurence adaptor in multiple fasta file

Tags: python, biopython

I have 30 fastq files in one folder and I want to know in which one of these files I can find a specific adaptor (so I can figure out which sample it actually is).

I wrote a tiny biopython script but it only allows me to look into one file at a time and I would like to count the occurence for each file at the same time. Can anybody help me improve the script?

```
 from Bio import SeqIO
 adaptor = (rec for rec in \
                SeqIO.parse("file.fastq", "fastq") \
                if rec.seq.startswith("TGA"))`
    count = SeqIO.write(adaptor, "adaptor.fastq", "fastq")
    print("Saved %i adaptor" % count)
```

Comment: You're looking to get the value for your `count` variable computed on each file that you have?

Comment: Basically, the adaptor should only be present in some of the files so I am trying to find a way to count the occurence of this adaptor for each file

Comment: Is that occurrence captured in the `count` variable that you have in your code?

Comment: The count variable should contain all sequences with the adaptor sequence present at the start if I am right

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with biopython, but it looks like you have computed what you need already (but you've only done so for a single file), and just need to do it for a bunch of files. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes , this is the part I am stuck! I am really new to bioinformatics but I am trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Bio import SeqIO
fnames = ["file.fastq", "file1.fastq", "file2.fastq"]
for fname in fnames:
    adaptor = (rec for rec in \
                    SeqIO.parse(fname, "fastq") \
                    if rec.seq.startswith("TGA"))
    count = SeqIO.write(adaptor, "adaptor.fastq", "fastq")
    print("Saved %i adaptor in file %s" %(count, fname))
```

Comment: Thanks now i understand how to input multiple fasta file. Is there a way to get one adaptor.fastq output file per input file?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with biopython, so I wouldn't be able to answer that. The docs should explain how to output a single adaptor. You could just stick that code into the for loop